# No puedo hacer ip ni puerto python flask chatterbot

Tags: python, flask

Me encuentro en un servidor que tiene cpanel y me da para hacer cosas con setup python app pero no me dan ningún tipo de ayuda porque lo he conseguido gratis.

Supuestamente es un servidor vps compartido

No puedo ir a http:// ip:5000 Porque tienen las ip y los puertos protegidos y no me quieren decir nada de nada...

Esta es mi supuesta ip address  y la app apunta al puerto 8080

pero 167.114.84.246:8080

Como puedo hacer?

Tengo instalado flask Y chatterbot en una carpeta que se llama toninot

Se puede hacer de alguna forma

https://intercongreso.vps.co.ve/toninot:5000 ????

Digo todo esto porque no me responde el chatbot....

Soy un novato y estoy perdido en el cosmos de la programacion :/

Comment: Cambia el puerto en que escucha flask, para que sea el que tengas abierto en el servidor (que no me ha quedado claro si es el 8080, la pregunta está redactada de forma muy confusa)

Comment: Bueno he buscado por la red como escanear para saber los puertos abiertos con un .py ... veo los puertos abiertos pero no funcionan... dice el terminal que están ocupados...